# wait until function call finishes in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
load_document(mobjson.ErrMsg, 1);
```

this function open create an pdf and open in new window and delete it on server everything is fine if pdf created is small but when it takes a little more time only in safari browser its execute to error:function({alert('error')}), rest of the browser is perfectly opening pdf .
i tried

```
setTimeout(function () {
                            load_document(mobjson.ErrMsg, 1);
                        }, 15000);
```

but dont know how long it will take for other pdf to be create ...
basically what i want is

```
load_document(mobjson.ErrMsg, 1);
wait till its complete then execute next line ..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into jQuery trigger() and on(). You can fire off a trigger event synchronously after the load_document function call and have the "next" function go when the event is triggered.

```
load_document(mobjson.ErrMsg, 1);
$(document).trigger('documentLoaded');
```

Then for the other action you need,

```
$(document).on('documentLoaded', function () {
    // do the next thing
});
```